# PHP CSV upload, wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I've made a lot of progress on this in some areas but struggling in others. Here's the objective: Existing wordpress site is being used by client. They want the admin user to access one of the front end pages with an upload option where they can upload a CSV (several daily). Then, upon accessing other pages in the portal, respective fields from the tables will be displayed (depending on the user). The CSV files have 201 fields, same order every time. In my php, I've setup a successful connection and coded 201 variables like so:

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "uwsTest";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo'success!';
}


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$coldata = array();

$coldata['orderNumber'] = $filesop[0];
$coldata['null'] = $filesop[1];
$coldata['workOrderNum'] = $filesop[2];
$coldata['lowSideMIUNum'] = $filesop[3];
$coldata['highSideMIUNum'] = $filesop[4];
$coldata['accountNum'] = $filesop[5];
$coldata['custName'] = $filesop[6];
```

Again, this line goes on through [200]. On the next portion, I will only paste certain variables to save space. This is where I index which tables certain variables will belong in.

```
$table_cols = array();

/*staging*/
$table_cols[0] ="null,orderNumber,null,workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum
/*clients*/
$table_cols[1] ="orderNumber,null,workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName
/*meters*/
$table_cols[2] ="workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName,address
/*tests*/
$table_cols[3] ="workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName,address
/*costs*/
$table_cols[4] ="workOrderNum,onsiteSurveyTestCost,onsiteSurveyTestRepairCost,offsiteSurveyTestCost
/*workorders*/
$table_cols[5] ="workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName
```

And now the SQL query:

```
$tablenames = array("staging","clients","meters","tests","costs","workorders");

for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++){
$q = "";
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$table_cols[$tableno].") VALUES (";
$cols = explode("," ,$table_cols);
$data = array();
foreach($col as $key => $fldname) {
    $data[] = "'".$coldata[$fldname]."'";
}

$q .= implode(",",$data).");";

}
echo'File submitted';
```

When I run this, I get no PHP errors. I run it on Mamp, upload the CSV through an html submit form, it calls the php and then on my php index page I get my messages for successful connection and successful insertion. However, when I look in MySQL workbench and select from tables they are empty. I think it looks like I need to create a table in MySQL workbench that has columns established for my PHP code. But I also need to grab these things and display them later on other pages of the site. Is there another issue here that could keep it from submitting?

Comment: If I understand right, there are no columns that correspond to the uploaded columns in the CSV.  Yes, that is would mean that the values are not saved to the database.  Is there a table(s) that corresponds to $tablenames[$tableno] in the database?  Every table will need the corresponding columns.

Comment: Well, I've removed headers from the CSV so it's only the data. But: I created the 201 fields in the PHP from the columns in the CSV so they correspond exactly. However, the database staging table was empty because I thought this would auto load everything. I'm currently making 201 fields in my table in MYSQL workbench that are named exactly like the variables in the PHP. But My $tablenames array holds the different table names that are in MYSQL workbench. The idea was to put everything in the staging table but also split everything among the other tables

Comment: I don't see where you're executing the query and if your POST array has value/is indeed set.

Comment: you also posted what seems to be the same question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/43006807/1415724 where you also don't appear to have executed the query using `mysqli_query($connect, $q)`.

Comment: POST should be working properly because it's tied to the submit button on the HTML form, so when I hit submit I get a php page with both success messages. Also, wouldn't the query be executing at the  q .= INSERT.... line?